# Normal maps looking low resolution and blurred

Tags: texturing

I have been trying to perfect my normal maps but i can never seem to get them right they always have this odd blurred out effect to them.

[image]

In this image i created shows my issue with normal mapping, as you can see it as a very low resolution blurred look regardless that the texture used is 4K.

Comment: Try to increase the contrast.

Comment: What the normal map is intended to do here ?

Comment: I was simply trying to give it depth to make it look more 3D but regardless of the texture i use i always end up getting this very nasty looking result. I followed Andrew Prices tutorial on this way back when and learnt how to do it but have never been able to get decent enough results from my normal mapping.

Comment: IMHO, without the blend file it is hard to see what is the problem here. If you want you can share your file (don't forget to pack the textures in it) here : http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Im afraid this file was lost along time ago although i can make a quick .blend for you which will no doubt give the same results.

Comment: Well... this is your question... personally, this is not mandatory !!

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/download/853klglg3ib98x2/SE.7z

Comment: This contains all the textures used plus the blend file

Comment: Well.. several factors : the lamp strength, the normal map strength, but above that, I think this is totally dependent of you NM texture... this texture is very contrasted so it influences a lot the normals of each rendered point

Comment: What would you recommend to make it look more realistic?

Comment: Totally dependent of the effect you want... Nothing is good or bad by definition. For instance, just moving the lamp (which is for now too perpendicular to the surface can change a lot the rendering)... You may provide an picture which is the result you want and someone here may find the way to do it

Comment: Also.. is this NM generated with Gimp ?

Comment: Just some free one online